# compute position of each symbol

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, positioning

I've created a program that generates clickable areas on images with HTML5, taking as input a series of coordinates.

Now what I'd like to do is send to that program a `.png` of a LaTeX expression (anything, for instance an equation or a sentence) along with the coordinates of the centers of each and every symbols of that expression.

The end goal is to make each symbol clickable separately from one another.

So I've been experimenting for a while to create an algorithm that would, given a latex expression, output the list of the coordinates of the centers of each of its symbols (that's the last piece I need to complete my program). Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with a nice solution.

However, this algorithm has to exist, since those symbols are indeed all properly located when one compiles a latex expression into a `.png`.

I've been searching in the TeX source code, with no success.

Comment: Are you actually speaking of MathJax? If yes, we are not the right site. Your question could better be answered on [MathJaX Help Forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users).

Comment: The required coordinates are probably pixels, right?